# Filtering input file with chunksize and skiprows using line number as index in dask dataframe

Tags: dask

I have ~70gb output of MD simulations. A pattern of a fixed-number-of-lines explanation and a fixed-number-of-lines data regularly repeat in the file. How can I read the file in Dask Dataframe chunk by chunk in which the explanation lines are ignored?

I successfully wrote a lambda function in the skiprows argument of the pandas.read_csv to ignore the explanation lines and only read the data lines. I converted the pandas-entered code to dask one but it does not work. Here you can see the dask code written by replacing pandas.read_csv with dd.read_csv:

```py
# First extracting number of atoms and hence, number of data lines:
with open(filename[0],mode='r') as file: # The same as Chanil's code
    line = file.readline()
    line = file.readline() 
    line = file.readline()
    line = file.readline() # natoms
    natoms = int(line)

skiplines = 9 # Number of explanation lines repeating after nnatoms lines of data

def logic_for_chunk(index):
    """This function read a chunk """
    if index % (natoms+skiplines) > 8:
       return False
    return True
df_chunk = dd.read_csv('trajectory.txt',sep=' ',header=None,index_col=False,skiprows=lambda x: logic_for_chunk(x),chunksize=natoms)
```

Here the indexes of the dataframe is line numbers of the file. Using above code, at the first chunk, lines 0 to 8 in file are ignored, then the lines 9 to 58 are read. At the next chunk, the line 59 to 67 are ignored and then a natoms-size chunk from line 68 to 117 are read. This happens until all the data snapshots are read.
Unfortunately, while the above code works well in pandas, it does not works in dask. How can I implement a similar procedure in dask dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

The dask dataframe read_csv function cuts the file up at byte locations.  It is unable to determine exactly how many lines are in each partition, so it is unwise to depend on the row index within each partition.

If there is some other way to detect a bad line then I would try that.  Ideally you will be able to determine a bad line based on the content of the line, not on its location within the file (like every  eighth line).